# Como gerar um nome de usuário tendo como referência seu nome real?

Tags: python

Estou com uma dúvida em como gerar nomes de usuários automaticamente a partir do nome real do usuário, de forma que o resultado seja referência ao nome real.

Sabendo que o método deve ser chamado informando o **nome completo** da pessoa e o **limite mínimo de caracteres** que terá este *nome de usuário*, além de verificar se este nome já existe e modifica-lo para não haver conflito, como seria feito essa operação?

```
nomes_de_usuarios_atuais = ['ACBETR', 'ZRPACA', 'TRDPOR', 'TRDPOR1']
def gerar_nome_de_usuario(nome, min_caracteres=6):
    # ...
    nomes_de_usuarios_atuais.append(nome_de_usuario)
    print nome_de_usuario

self.assertEqual(gerar_nome_de_usuario('Luis Inacio Lula Da Silva', 6), 'LILDSI')
self.assertEqual(gerar_nome_de_usuario('Ricardo Magalhães', 6), 'RMAGAL')
self.assertEqual(gerar_nome_de_usuario('Ana Carolina Viana', 6), 'ACVIAN')
self.assertEqual(gerar_nome_de_usuario('David Rio', 6), 'DRIO01')
self.assertEqual(gerar_nome_de_usuario('Luis Inacio Lula Da Silva', 6), 'LILDSI1')
```

No caso o retorno deve ser as iniciais do nome completo. Caso o nome completo tenha poucas palavras, <strike>o algoritmo deve pegar mais letras (ex: *'Luis Inacio'* ficaria *'LUIINA'*)</strike> a ultima palavra deverá completar, e se assim ainda não resultar em no mínimo 6 caracteres, deve adicionar números ao final. Se o resultado final conflitar com nomes de usuários já cadastrados, o algoritmo deve adicionar um número ao final.

Comment: Esta pergunta me parece muita ampla e/ou subjetiva: há N maneiras de se fazer isso, e a "qualidade" do resultado vai depender muito do gosto de cada um. Por favor tente restringir mais o que você espera de uma resposta, caso contrário vai muito na opinião de cada um.

Comment: Agora está bem mais específico (e "respondível"). Uma dúvida: se você já adicionou números no final por falta de caracteres suficientes (ex.: `DRIO01`) e esse nome conflitou com outro já existente, você muda o número no final ou acrescenta mais um número?

Comment: Após o seu comentário acabei editando a pergunta para especificar melhor o resultado final, o que acabou simplificando a lógica.

Comment: @mgibsonbr no caso seria mudado, se não pode haver mais repetições e ficar muito extenso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minha sugestão é primeiro montar o "radical" do nome (a parte antes do número) e, em seguida, usar um contador para determinar o sufixo mais adequado (se algum):

```
radical = ''.join(x[0] for x in nome.split(' '))
if len(radical) < min_caracteres:
    radical += nome.split(' ')[-1][1:min_caracteres - len(radical) + 1]

radical = radical.upper()
```

Se o radical for menor que o tamanho mínimo, um ou mais dígitos será necessário. Uma maneira de simplificar a lógica é criando um padrão de formatação que exija no mínimo aquele número de dígitos:

```
formatar = "{:0" + str(min_caracteres - len(radical)) + "d}"
# Ex.: "{:03d}".format(12) ==> 012
```

Então é só criar um contador e usar no final do nome:

```
if len(radical) < min_caracteres or radical in nomes_de_usuarios_atuais:
    contador = 1
    while radical + formatar.format(contador) in nomes_de_usuarios_atuais:
        contador += 1
    nome_de_usuario = radical + formatar.format(contador)
else:
    nome_de_usuario = radical
```

> *Nota:* A resposta anterior (em arquivo) não responde à pergunta após os esclarecimentos.